# issue with numbering how can i fix the numbering?

Tags: css

I have the next issue when I try to numbering the list

```css
.contenido ol {    
    padding-left: 0px;
    counter-reset: item;
}

.contenido ol  > li {
    display: block;
}

.contenido ol > li::before { 
  content: counters(item,  ". ") " " ; 
  counter-increment: item;
}

.contenido ol ol > li {
    display: block;
}

.contenido ol ol > li::before {    
  content: counters(item,  ". ") ". " ; 
}
```

and the html I have:

```html
<div id="test">
  <ol>
    <li> item1</li>
    <li> item2

    <ol>
      <li>item 2.1</li>
      <li>item 2.2
      <ol>
        <li>item a</li>
        <li>item b</li>
        <li>item c </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>item 2.3</li>
    </ol>
    <li>item 3</li>
  <ol>

</div>
```

In the page showed:

```
1. item1
2. item2 
   1. item 2.1 --- in this part I want to show as 2.1
   2. item 2.2 --- in this part I want to show as 2.2
      a. item a
      b. item b
      c. item c
   3. item 2.3 --- in this part I want to show as 2.3
3. item 3
```

Comment: the class "contenido" is inside of the div; like : div id="test"> div class="contenido">

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine with me. Its rendering by my browser showed your wishes.
 If you perchange want to omit the a/b/c-items from the numbering, you can try to be more specific:

CSS:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#contentar>ol>li::before,
#contentar>ol>li>ol>li::before{
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section,".") " ";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contentar">
  <ol>
    <li> item1</li>
    <li> item2
    <ol>
      <li>item 2.1</li>
      <li>item 2.2
      <ol>
         <li>item a</li>
         <li>item b</li>
         <li>item c </li>
      </ol>
      </li>
    <li>item 2.3</li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```